# Unable to trigger Redux action after ajax

Tags: reactjs, redux

Fairly new to React-Redux here.

Basically, I am trying to get the store to update with the username after the login is successful.

Here is the JSX part:

```
    <form id='loginForm' onSubmit={(e) => (this.handleSubmit(e).then(function(response){ this.props.loggedIn(this.state.username)}))}>
      <label>Login ID</label>
      <input type='text' name='username' id='username' placeholder='Enter your login ID' value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChangeUsername}/>
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type='password' name='password' id='password' placeholder='Enter your Password' value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChangePassword}/>
      <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Sign In' className="blueButton"/>
    </form>
```

`handleSubmit()` returns AJAX using the Axios module.

I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
```

If the `onSubmit` is set to `this.props.loggedIn.bind(null, 'sampleUsername')` directly, the action does get triggered. However, no ajax call obviously.

Any pointers?

Comment: bind then function. `this` is wrongly used and does not point to the react component. or try using arrow function.

Comment: @ReiDien Than you! That fixed it. :)

Comment: glad to help :)